# unable to wget on https://autoscaling.amazonaws.com/ from AWS Ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy

getting below error when running wget on https://autoscaling.amazonaws.com from an ec2 instance

Exact wget used :

```
wget https://autoscaling.amazonaws.com

Resolving autoscaling.amazonaws.com (autoscaling.amazonaws.com)... 
Connecting to autoscaling.amazonaws.com (autoscaling.amazonaws.com)||:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

 (try: 2)  https://autoscaling.amazonaws.com/
Connecting to autoscaling.amazonaws.com (autoscaling.amazonaws.com)||:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

(try: 3)  https://autoscaling.amazonaws.com/
```

i do have autoscaling.amazonaws.com & s3.amazonaws.com in no_proxy & NO_PROXY env variables

when i tried

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com

    Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)||:443... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
    Location: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/ [following]
   --  https://aws.amazon.com/s3/
    Resolving **-proxy-**.**.**.com (**-**-**.**.**.com)... 
    Connecting to **-proxy-**.**.**.com (**-proxy-**.**.**.com)|... connected.
    ERROR: cannot verify aws.amazon.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=*,OU=*,O=*,L=*,ST=*,C=*’:
      Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
```

So for S3 atleast it connected and gave certificate error

Comment: Just to be sure, can you include the exact full wget command , that led to the results above? And secondly, whether this command is still producing the same response, or if you now get a different response.

Comment: Could you please try and confirm , whether you can able to access others URL's with same NO_PROXY config?

Comment: @clarity123 ,@Katha Muthu  updated my question

Comment: @shiv455, If you properly add IP/Hostname in NO_PROXY variable ,It should not try to query proxy for internet connection . As per your case,"https://autoscaling.amazonaws.com" properly added, So you need to check you VPC settings (Security group,Routing table,Internet gateway.etc)..(Try to ping Google ,then you can come to know the connection status,Accordingly you change the parameter)..

Comment: S3 would connect if you have a VPC Gateway for S3, so may not be a valid test.